# JSON.NET WPF or Winform C# sample

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, json.net

i am less into WPF and Winforms. I want to create a WPF or Winform application that when i enter a text in textBox1, textBox2, textBox3 and textBox4, all those text are combined to create/update a *.json file and a *.XML file at the same time using JSON.NET library [http://james.newtonking.com/json]. All the documentation i have found are very complex to integrate to UI (atleast fo me). I know what you are about to ask me, "what have you done yourself??"...yeah, that's a cool question...my answer is, when learning something new, i need to see it in action... Please help... A downloadable sample will be better

Answer (score 0):

Rather than giving you the code I will try to help you learn how to tackle new problems and help you if you get stuck.

So, lets break this big task into several smaller ones:

- Creating UI
- Create XML string
- Create JSON string
- Save the string to a file

If you have trouble with the first task, I suggest going through a WinForms quick tutorial.

For the last task, simplest way to go is

```
File.WriteAllText(path, text);
```

Try to solve these 2 problems first and get back to us if you get stuck. Good luck!

Comment: I like your style solving problems,